# delete category name in the pages

Tags: categories

I'm looking for a way so that I can delete category's name in the pages.

I tried to find something for category in index.php but I couldn't find anything.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***What theme are you running?***

Are you referring to **Pages** or **Posts** because they are two different **types** or rather, what we call **Post Types**.

- **Pages** are normally controlled via your `page.php` template file
- **Posts** are normally controlled via your `single.php` template file

Commonly you will find category and tag functions in your `single.php` file, but calls to such functions are not strictly limited to a `single.php` file. They can in fact be used in multiple theme files.

So for example,

- if you are viewing a **Single Post**, then look within `single.php`
- if you are viewing a **list of your Posts**, then look within `archive.php`

You will be looking for template tags such as,

```
<?php the_category(); ?>

  or...

<?php the_tags(); ?>
```